# Erlang and current date time

Tags: time, erlang

I would like to get a current date time with erlang.
I have tried using the code below;

```
{{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Min,Sec}} = erlang:localtime().
```

But sometimes it got an error like '** exception error: no match of right hand side value {{2012,5,6},{23,40,58}}'

Looks like there is a problem with 1 digit. I try searching couple of webs but still cannot find a way to cope this.

I believe this is quite an easy one but as a erlang newbie, I cannot resolve this. I try my best.

Env:
Erlang {"OTP  APN 181 01","R15B01"} installed with windows binary version
Windows XP

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no problem with 1 digit. It should match perfectly well (check with `{{Year,Month,Day},{Hour,Min,Sec}} = {{2012,5,6},{23,40,58}}`). Most likely you have already assigned one of the variables to something earlier in the function.

Comment: Looks like it is. If we assigned one of the variables to something earlier. How can I clear it?

Comment: I got how to reset bound variables via google. Thanks for your answer :). This is the first time I get into erlang. A lot to learn.